# org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: Unhandled exception type Exception

Tags: rythm

When trying out the rythm template code below via the Rythm engine fiddle at http://fiddle.rythmengine.com/#/editor

I get the error:

```
org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: Unhandled exception type Exception
```

the template I tried is:

```
 @{
        class Field {
           String description;
           String getDescription() throws Exception {
              return description;
           }
        }
        Field field=new Field();
        field.description="test";
    }

the field description is: @(field.getDescription())
```

I have looked thru the documentation for some kind of try/catch construct and consulted my favorite search engine. I didn't find a hint on how to handle exceptions.

**How are exceptions to be handled in Rythm template code?**

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you do NOT throw out checked exception. Change your code to :

```
@{
        class Field {
           String description;
           String getDescription() throws RuntimeException {
              return description;
           }
        }
        Field field=new Field();
        field.description="test";
    }

the field description is: @(field.getDescription())
```

And it should work

Comment: This is just an example. What if i can't change my code?

Comment: well I don't see any reason to support CheckedException inside a template code. But if you have a really good reason I can consider change the behavior